# how can i make this form not send?

Tags: javascript, html

`<form id="form5" method="POST" action="/DataHandlers/CreateContentItem.ashx"onsubmit="SubmitForm(this,null);return false;">`
(my form tag)
This is the submit button -
`<button type="submit">send</button>`

My javascript code -

```
function SubmitForm(formElement, funcToRun) {
    if (FormChecks()) {
        var fd = new FormData(formElement);
        CallHTTPHandler(formElement.action, funcToRun, fd);
    }
}

function FormChecks() {
    var errors = []
    var password = document.getElementById("input_password");
    if (/[^a-z0-9]/i.test(password.value)) {
        errors.push("*Password must only be A-Z, a-z or 0-9")
    }
    //one example of the checks, there are like 20
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            
            errorElement.innerHTML = errors.join(', ')
            console.log(errors)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

i tried to make the code shorter here since its way too long, but to get to my question
how can i make the form not send if FormChecks returns false?

Comment: could it be that you want to [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to this:

```
onsubmit="SubmitForm(this,null);return false;"
```

If there is any kind of error in `SubmitForm`, the code `return false;` will not execute, and the form **will** be submitted.

To test this, consider the following that excludes `SubmitForm(...)`:

```html
<form id="form5" method="POST" action="/DataHandlers/CreateContentItem.ashx" onsubmit="return false;">
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

You can see that the form is **not** being submitted.  Therefore, I can only conclude that an error is occurring in your JS code for `SubmitForm(...)` and `return false;` never executes (thus the submit is never prevented).